# Slow boot 1min 2.440s dev-sda1.device due to Google Drive?

Tags: 16.04, boot

My Ubuntu 16.04 is taking quite a time to boot up. I took a look at `systemd-analyze`, `dmesg` and I don't know how to fix it: any ideas?

[image: dmesg output]

[image: systemd-analyze blame]

`/etc/fstab` content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=40bb1e94-d051-458c-8a4c-213a80600b47 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=81b0487e-bcec-4e49-b88c-a3c7ff112ec2 none            swap    sw              0       0
gdfuse#default  /home/onion/Documents fuse uid=1000,gid=1000,user       0       0
```

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT                                                                                                                  
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom                                                                                                                              
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk                                                                                                                             
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part                                                                                                                             
├─sda5   8:5    0   7,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0   225G  0 part /
```

Comment: Would you like to give us the output for the `journalctl` command?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @Mkay  forum says the output is too long, do i have an alternative?

Comment: @MKay i have added a link to the journalctl file, thanks.

Comment: Did you try commenting the last line in your `/etc/fstab`? And if root partition is on `/dev/sda1` and swap is on `/dev/sda5` what is there on 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: Please include the output from `lsblk` using copy and paste instead of screen snapshot.

Comment: lsblk added: according to gparted sda5 is inside sda2: @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @MKay last line of fstab is my gdrive :)

Comment: @user1800535 I would comment out the fstab entry for google drive and reboot to see if that speeds it up. If it does I would move the google drive mount to startup applications.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes removing gdfuse improved a lot but in that case my google drive is not loaded automatically. And there is not application to start it up.

This is what i did to integrate google drive : https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Automounting

it requieres a script and modifying fstab. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1800535 I posted an answer and took the liberty of adding **Google Drive** to your question title. I can roll back the changes to the title if you feel it wasn't the cause of slow booting.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Drive from Linux

The instructions you were following to setup google drive access within Linux were a little outdated. [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/mount-google-drive-ocamlfuse-linux) has easier instructions from April 2017 that don't involve modifying `/etc/fstab` which slows down your boot.

### Install Google Drive Ocamlfuse for Ubuntu 16.04 and up

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

### Configure Google Drive Ocamlfuse

With the install complete you can go ahead and set up the app to work with your Google Drive account. While there isn’t a fancy-pants GUI front-end for setting things up don’t feel put. GDO is super simple to use via the CLI.

To get started run the app from the command line using this command:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

The first time you do this the utility will create all the relevant config files and folders it needs to mount your Google Drive account. It will also launch your default web browser so that you sign in and authorize access to your Google Drive files.

Sign in with your Google username and password and, when the screen above appears, grant the utility permission to access your files and folders.

That’s it; you’re pretty much good to go!

### Create directory for Google Drive

All that’s left is to create an empty folder in which to mount Google Drive on your system.

```
mkdir ~/googledrive
```

### Mount Google Drive

Once a Google Drive directory is created go ahead and mount it there by running this command:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/googledrive
```

Pop open Nautilus (or whichever modern file manager you use) and you will see your Google Drive mount listed in the sidebar as a device.

### Unmount Google Drive

When you’re finished editing, adding or copying files you can unmount the fuse filesystem with this command:

```
fusermount -u ~/google-drive
```

You can try to unmount it using the eject button you’ll see in Nautilus, Nemo, etc but this won’t work; you’ll get a permissions error.